# Saltstack pillars are empty when I execute pillar.items?

Tags: salt-stack

I am trying to initialise pillars in my salt states but when I refresh the pillars and try to look at the data using `pillar.item` or `pillar.ls` , I am not able to see it.

My Folder structure at `/srv/salt/base` -

[image]

- `/etc/salt/master.d/roots.conf` has the following

[image]

Output when I run `pillar.item`-
[image]

Unable to figure out the problem here?

Comment: Please post your top.sls of your pillars.

Comment: DO NOT PUT PILLARS UNDER THE FILESERVER - it exposes all the secrets to every minion. `/srv/pillar` would be the default file root.

Comment: @SynPrime OrangeDog Ironically, I tried putting the pillars in /srv/pillar and the solution is working. Why can't I explicitly set another path for pillars?